# Identify lazy grading from distribution of test scores?

Tags: probability, distributions

For the end-terms in a large public university (LPU), there were qualitative tests for 5 courses.  Every one of the 1000 students took every test, so there are 5000 answer scripts. Every test was scored between 0 and 100, so each student could get an aggregate score between 0 and 500.  The scripts were distributed over 50 TAs for grading. Is it possible to identify lazy grading (i.e. the TAs did not do their job conscientiously) from the distribution of *aggregate* scores?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to aggregate that data, can you talk about how they were aggregated?  Do you have some hypothesis about what lazy TA grading might look like in the aggregate data?

Comment: with the information given I don't see how. Maybe it could be possible under some strong assumptions, but I don't see how they'd be tenable.

Comment: If the assumption of random assignment of students to TAs in tenable and a given TA was solely responsible for any given student, then there might be a solution... but not one that I'd rely on to mark out 'bad TAs' unless it so happened that TA 6 gave everyone the same score or something equally absurd.

Comment: @Russell: The aggregation is the simple summation of the scores in each of the 5 tests. The assumption is that the scripts were randomly distributed over the TAs, but most of the TAs were lazy and simply "eyeballed" the scripts. My feeling is that this would generate a normal distribution, which would not happen if the scoring is done properly.

Comment: Well, if that is a safe assumption (that the distribution should not be normal), then you could test whether normality was violated (and by how much).  Obviously you couldn't endorse the null as posed by typical statistics for this sort of thing (that the data is normal).  However, from an abstract standpoint I'm a little skeptical that the distribution would be normal only under those circumstances.

Comment: On what basis can you assert "*which would not happen if the scoring is done properly*"?

Comment: @Glen_b: This is a presumption/extrapolation. The SAT scores of the students are not normally distributed (more precisely, skewed). The students are all freshmen.

Comment: I don't see that it justifies the assumption of non-normality with respect to a different instrument. For example, the rationale that wikipedia gives for the skewness in SATs would not seem to apply. This is one of the things I had in mind when I originally referred to 'strong', but not 'tenable' assumptions -- assuming a specific distributional shape on the basis of vague analogy rather than actual evidence.

Comment: @Glen_b: Can you suggest any other alternative for tracking a hunch about lazy grading?

Comment: I can only repeat my first comment - with the information given, I don't see how

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the relationship between the individual students marks assigned by each scorer and the students overall mark without the mark from that scorer. Just plot the values as a big scatter graph with one dot for each student scored by the scorer in question (one scatter plot for each scorer). You can expect to see an obvious correlation if (i) the scorer is diligent and (ii) the assessment tasks discriminate similarly between the good and bad students.

Use the range of observed patterns to see whether the marks from some scorers correlate less well with the student's overall performance than others. If a scorer is giving random marks then there will be no correlation, but don't expect a particularly strong correlation for even a very diligent scorer.

Comment: The problem is that the uni releases only the aggregate scores (summed on 500). The presumption is that the TAs have essentially formed a cartel and none of them are grading diligently.

Comment: I don't know how to do anything useful with the aggregate data. It is sometimes hard to get useful data from my university too.